# Why don't Perl attribute handlers get called from other packages?

Tags: perl, attributes, custom-attributes

I am having a strange problem with Attribute::Handlers that looks like some kind of bug:

```
package MyPackage;

use Attribute::Handlers;

sub UNIVERSAL::foo :ATTR(CODE) {
  ...
}
```

When used in MyPackage, or from the main package of a script that uses MyPackage, the foo handler is called whenever the compiler comes across a function of the form

```
sub bar:foo {
 ...
}
```

However, I have another package, in a separate .pm file, that uses MyPackage. The compiler accepts the ":foo" attribute, but the handler is *not* called.

I tried writing an import function in MyPackage that exports the foo handler to the caller's namespace, but that doesn't seem to help.

Can anyone make sense of this? I've been racking my brain for the past few days over how to fix this.

Comment: Are you `use`ing `strict` and `warnings` already?

Comment: @Chris - Yes. I am starting to suspect that one of the other packages that I am using is conflicting with Attribute:Handlers.

Comment: Can you add more code here? Some fully functional example of what you are doing and how it is not working?

Comment: The module that I am having these problems with is at https://github.com/robrwo/File-Temp-Trace

Answer (score 3):

By default, attribute handlers are called in the CHECK block after the compilation phase.

If the "using" package uses `eval "use packagename";` then only BEGIN blocks will be executed. CHECK blocks won't be executed, and the attribute handlers won't be called.

Try using `ATTR(CODE,BEGIN)` to execute the handler in the BEGIN block.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow totally missed the Attribute::Handlers in your post yesterday - as mentioned in my comment to the older version of this answer, perhaps wrapping the `use MyPackage` in a `BEGIN` block will cause things to be resolved properly.

I'm unsure as to why you chose to put the `foo()` attribute handler in `UNIVERSAL` - was that a step toward trying to get it to work?

Comment: I did, and missed it. As far as I can tell from your post and the docs you are doing it right. Answer updated with some speculations as to things to try.

Comment: Joe, I put it in UNIVERSAL so other modules can use the attributes. That's what Attribute::Handlers recommends.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Putting a `use package` inside of a `BEGIN` block is completely redundant. `use` statements are always executed in the same phase as `BEGIN` blocks.